# Do not count the white space in the text box

Tags: c#

I have written a program that calculates the number of characters in a word entered in the text box, but I  do not want to count the number of whitespaces.
 What code should I write? For example, when Max is written inside the text box, the number of letters is 3  and 3 appears in other textbox, then if whitespace is used in textbox, the number of letters remains the same as 3 and does not change.

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a;
    int asc , j=0;
    kabir = 0;
    vasit = 0;
    textBox2.Text =" ";
    for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
    {
        int t = abjad_kabir(Char.ConvertToUtf32(textBox1.Text.Substring(i, 1), 0));
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(t);
        j++;
        // I want to  do not appear number of white spaces in textbox3 and just count number of letters
        textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code to better illustrate your description

Comment: Print your result in In "text_changed" method. In it count characters which does not contain space character.

Comment: Some hints.  The `Text` property of a textbox is of type `string`.  If you `foreach` over a `string`, you get items of type `char`. The `char` type has a static method named `IsWhiteSpace`.

Comment: @sam if i understand correctly what your're looking you have 2 way :
first you can split the result by (space char) result.split(' ') and get the max len off all word present on the result array. 
The second way it's to replace (space char) by '' result.replace(' ','').len and get the len.

Comment: @sam, please update the question with the needed info(i.e the code you have written and the result you expect)

Comment: @sam Code in comments is not useful.  Click "Edit" under the question and paste your code into the question, formatted so its readable.

Comment: @sam : check this link out. hope it solves your issue. : 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/062rg1

Comment: I solved this problem by using of  trim() method.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the characters that you don't want with a regular expression and count the remaining characters:

```
var text = "Max   Length";
Console.WriteLine("Length={0}", Regex.Replace(text, @"\W+", "").Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Linq for this:

```
var count = text.Count(c => c != ' ');
```

Comment: @Breeze to reiterate the question was "Do not count the white space in the text box", for anything else the OP needs to clarify.

Comment: tab is also considered a whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

I could delete white spaces by `Trim()` method.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a;
    int asc, j = 0;
    kabir = 0;
    vasit = 0;
    textBox2.Text = " ";
    string s, m;
    for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
    {
        int p = Char.ConvertToUtf32(textBox1.Text.Substring(i, 1), 0);
        int t = abjad_kabir(p);
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(t);
        s = textBox1.Text;
        m = s.Trim();
        textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(m.Length);
    }
}
```